# Inserting two logos on title page, on top right and top left corner

Tags: graphics, titles

Well here's my problem, inserting two logos in top right and top left corner of title page.
Here's the code that I've tried:

```
\begin{titlepage}
\raggedright{\includegraphics[width = 40mm]{logoInsa.png}\\[8ex]}
\raggedleft{\includegraphics[width = 40mm]{logoInsa.png}\\[8ex]}
\begin{center}
blablabla
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

The problem here is that it adds the first logo in the top left corner, but the second logo is added on the right, on the next line. How can I put it on the same line? I've tried many things and I saw "beamer" on forums, but I don't know what's that and couldn't understand. Do you know some easy way to do it?
Here's what happens when I run the code:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\raggedright` and `\raggedleft` do not take arguments so never use as `\raggedright{...}` but here you do not want them at all just

```
\begin{titlepage}
\includegraphics[width = 40mm]{logoInsa.png}%
\hfill
\includegraphics[width = 40mm]{logoInsa.png}

\centering
zzzz
```